# Check if secure transfer is enabled in azure storage account

Tags: java, azure

We can set if secure tansfer is enabled or not when creating storage account in azure portal but is there a way to check if a storage account is enabled or not through api/sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do so. If you're using Storage Resource Provider's [`Get Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/getproperties) operation on a storage account, you will see a property called `supportsHttpsTrafficOnly`. True value indicates that secure transfer is enabled and false value indicates it otherwise.

I have not used Java SDK but a quick look at [`StorageAccount`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/storage/resource-manager/v2019_04_01/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/storage/v2019_04_01/StorageAccount.java) class indicates that this capability is exposed through `enableHttpsTrafficOnly()` property. So it should be possible to get this information through SDK as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information in multiple ways depending on your preference:

- Azure CLI
- Azure PowerShell
- .Net Fluent SDK
- Java SDK
- and other SDKs that exist

Here are the snippets reduced to only display the value of the field.
Replace the placeholders <..> with their real values. The storage account will be identified by resource group name and storage account name.
The solutions presume that you now how to authenticate.

### Azure CLI

```
az storage account show --resource-group <ResourceGroupName> --name <StorageAccountName> --query enableHttpsTrafficOnly
```

### Azure PowerShell

```
Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <StorageAccountName> | Select-Object EnableHttpsTrafficOnly
```

### Fluent SDK (C# console app)

```
//requires references for Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent and Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent

IAzure myAzure = Azure.Authenticate("azure.auth").WithDefaultSubscription();    
Console.WriteLine(myAzure.StorageAccounts.GetByResourceGroup("<ResourceGroupName>", "<StorageAccountName>").Inner.EnableHttpsTrafficOnly);
```

### Java SDK

There is also an SDK for Java and it seems to work in an identical fashion. Looking at the code, you should be able to achieve the same, as with the .NET SDK.

Here is a link for storage account management samples with Java and the SDK:
[Java SDK Storage Account Management](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-java-manage-storage-accounts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/storage/samples/ManageStorageAccount.java) Go to the section *List storage accounts* and adapt the sample similar to my C# code (apply getByResourceGroup(...) and .Inner.enableHttpsTrafficOnly

I hope this is of some help.